# Android Studio in hardware device

Tags: android-studio

```
7/12/20
```

12:11 AM    * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037

12:11 AM    * daemon started successfully

12:11 AM    Gradle sync started

12:12 AM    Gradle sync finished in 8 s 433 ms (from cached state)

12:13 AM    Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project /home/memenomentomori/AndroidStudioProjects/KIDKH

12:14 AM    Gradle build failed with 1 error(s) in 42 s 763 ms

I'm running the Android Studio 4.0 in

- OS        : Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
- Memory    : 3.7 GiB
- Processor : Intel® Core™ i7-4720HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz × 8
- Graphics  : GeForce GTX 950M/PCIe/SSE2
- GNOME     : 3.28.2
- OS Type   : 64-bit
- Disk      : 984.4 GB

I'm using my phone (Samsung Galaxy Note 9) as an emulator, but it keeps me showing this error code "Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed)". I only used Basic Activity as my project template, I am new to this, so I am saying my sorry in advance.